# Is FT1248 same as Quad / Octo SPI?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, ftdi

When reading through the FTDI FT232H datasheet, I saw that the device can be configured as a "FT1248" slave. To me, the protocol they outline looks exactly like half-duplex 2/4/8-bit parallel SPI.
Am I missing some key difference? Does anyone have any experience in interfacing the FT232H with a microcontroller in multi-bit parallel SPI?